# how to fix new (buggy?) behavior of javascript Selection.modify("move","backward","lineboundary")

Tags: javascript

[Selection.modify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/modify) is causing me headaches. The normal behavior of `sel.modify("move","backward","lineboundary")`, where `sel` is the current selection, is to move the caret to the beggining of the current line in a contenteditable. In recent versions of chrome (and other browsers, e.g. brave), the following new behavior occurs: if the line of the current caret is empty, then the caret goes back to the beginning of the whole contenteditable.

- Am I crazy, or is this a bug? I tried to report it, to no avail.
- Any simple solution to revert to the old behavior? (that doesn't involve complicated find-caret-position/read-character-after-caret operations). That means, if the line is empty, it shouldn't do anything.

Comment: "I tried to report it, to no avail" where did you report it? Can you link to this? Certainly the devs that are responsible for this change will be the best to explain why they made that change. This method is unfortunately not part of [the specs](https://w3c.github.io/selection-api/#selection-interface), so they can actually do whatever they want... and you should not use it in your code. ([here is a specs issue](https://github.com/w3c/selection-api/issues/37) discussing it and its problems). So currently it seems you will have to analyze the content yourself...

Comment: "and you should not use it in your code." are there any decent substitutes? managing the caret in a contenteditable is not simple...

Comment: "you will have to analyze the content yourself...", sorry, I know your pain. This side of the web APIs is really missing a lot of love and it's a browser-vendors/platforms/locales mess that makes all this so much complicated to deal with... But still, where did you post the bug report? Certainly the ones that made the change had a good idea of why they did it.

Comment: "But still, where did you post the bug report?" probably in the wrong place. in fact, I can't find a link to it in my records. where would be a good place to post it?

Comment: https://crbug.com

Comment: thanks! reported https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1221539